Combined reliability for statistically independent tests/measurements
I'm perplexed by this statement in Wikipedia article, 'Consilience':
"Statistically, if three different tests are each 90% reliable when they give a positive result, a positive result from all three tests would be 99.9% reliable; five such tests would be 99.999% reliable, and so forth. This requires the tests to be statistically independent, analogous to the requirement for independence in the methods of measurement."

How are these reliability percentages calculated? For example, if the 4 independent tests had different reliabilities, say, 77%, 88%, 90%, and 93%, what would their combined reliability be?

What is the statistics term for this phenomenon?


Thanks!

I don't like the use of 'reliable' here - it has a specific meaning in statistical analysis. Instead I would say that the tests have 90% sensitivity - that is, if a person has the disease, there is a 90% probability that the the person has the disease (also called the true positive rate).

This is called the "multiplication rule", which states that $P(A \cap B)=P(A).P(B)$, if and only if A and B are independent (the more general rule, which applies even if A and B are not independent, is $P(A \cap B)=P(A).P(B|A)$ (e.g. see here). In your example, assuming independence of all 4 tests, this is just the product of the 4 reliabilities, or rather of the 4 failure rates (which are (1 - reliability)): the probability that all 4 tests "fail" is the product of the 4 failure rates $(1-.77)*(1-.88)(1-.9).(1-.93)=0.00019$. Hence the reliability of the 4 tests combined is $(1-0.00019)=99.9807%$.

If the tests make the same predictions, how can they be independent?

Because they could use very different technologies (with different error modes) to arrive at the same result. E.g. a lateral flow COVID test (based on antigens), vs a PCR COVID test (based on RNA); they test the same thing, but different technologies, and therefore different error modes, hence independent. In fact, even if it is the exact same test; this is the logic behind repeating a test giving an "unexpected" result; some error modes would be correlated, others not... Doctors would treat them as independent... Btw, I was just answering the OP's premise (3 different but independent tests)

Thank you, jginestet, for this admirably clear--and rapid!--explanation. Perplexity evaporated!
